# SQL relationships for unique sets of rows

Tags: sql, many-to-many

I am trying to set up a relationship between a couple of tables where a unique set of rows in one table relate to a row in another table.

I have came up with a scenario to reflect what I am trying to accomplish.

In this scenario, we are trying to determine the role(s) that a new hire should be given, based on the set of skills that they posses. An employee can be given multiple roles. For example, a software engineer with management experience is given both the Software Engineer and the Tech Lead roles. However, the roles given must line up exactly with a given skill set. If a new hire comes in with every skill we are looking for, we give them the CTO role. The CTO posses all of the skills for both the Software Engineer and Tech Lead roles, but they are not given those roles.

I believe my issue boils down to the `skill_set` relationship, where I am trying to tie a unique set of rows from the `skill` table to a specific `skill_set`. Any given `skill` can be in many `skill_sets`, but when querying for a `skill_set`, I only want to return the `skill_set` that contains all of the `skills`, but currently I don't know of a good way to query for that specific `skill_set`

We don't need to worry about trying to find roles for lists of `skills` that aren't valid `skill_sets`. Those can return no role.

Note: This schema is not set in stone. Changing it is definitely an option, so if I have modeled this incorrectly, we can fix that.

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `skill`  (
  `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `skill_set` (
  `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `skill_id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`, `skill_id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `default_role` (
  `skill_set_id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `role_id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`skill_set_id`, `role_id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `role` (
  `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
 ) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `skill` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
  ('1', 'python'),
  ('2', 'javascript'),
  ('3', 'ec2'),
  ('4', 'docker'),
  ('5', 'management');

INSERT INTO `skill_set` (`id`, `skill_id`) VALUES
  ('1', '1'),
  ('2', '2'),
  ('3', '1'),
  ('3', '2'),
  ('4', '3'),
  ('5', '4'),
  ('6', '1'),
  ('6', '2'),
  ('6', '5'),
  ('7', '3'),
  ('7', '4'),
  ('7', '5'),
  ('8', '1'),
  ('8', '2'),
  ('8', '3'),
  ('8', '4'),
  ('8', '5');

INSERT INTO `default_role` (`skill_set_id`, `role_id`) VALUES
  ('1', '1'),
  ('2', '1'),
  ('3', '2'),
  ('4', '3'),
  ('5', '3'),
  ('6', '2'),
  ('6', '4'),
  ('7', '3'),
  ('7', '4'),
  ('8', '5');

INSERT INTO `role` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
  ('1', 'Junior Software Engineer'),
  ('2', 'Software Engineer'),
  ('3', 'DevOps Engineer'),
  ('4', 'Tech Lead'),
  ('5', 'CTO');
```

A SQL fiddle is also available: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/86bcfe0

Some example outputs:

---

Given the skills: ['python']

Return the default role: Junior Software Engineer

---

Given the skills: ['python', 'javascript']

Return the default role: Software Engineer

---

Given the skills: ['ec2']

Return the default role: DevOps Engineer

---

Given the skills: ['python', 'javascript', 'management']

Return the default roles: Software Engineer, Tech Lead

---

Given the skills: ['python', 'javascript', 'ec2', 'docker', 'management']

Return the default role: CTO

Comment: Specify the expected result as well. And show us your current query attempt.

Comment: I added expected output, but my current query attempt is essentially non-existant. This whole process starts with trying to get a `skill_set` from a unique group of `skills`, which is where I am having trouble.